# BigQuery has region restriction or delay between other regions?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to store data on BigQuery from GCE instance, and query to it from different region instance.
e.g.)store data from EU instance, query from US instance.

Is this possible without any delay?
I think it would take some times to replicate data to other region.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> BigQuery has region restriction ...?

There are few, like below

1. You cannot copy tables between EU and US regions. You will get something like below
   *Cannot read and write in different locations: source: US, destination: EU*
2. Also you cannot query data in US and EU within the same query. You will get something like below
   *Cannot process data across locations: EU,US*

> I think it would take some times to replicate data to other region.

There is no any replication when you do query. You just query data where it is / in that region (if you have access of course)

> Is this possible without any delay?

Thus no delay related to replication, as there is no replication!!

Comment: Thank you for your great answer!  
I just realized BQ regions.