# Errors: Cannot read and write in different locations: source: EU, destination: US (error code: invalid)

Tags: google-bigquery

I have this error in BigQuery:

Errors:
Cannot read and write in different locations: source: EU, destination: US (error code: invalid)

I don't know how I can fix it... please give me ideas
My query is:

```
SELECT     
      ROUTER_MAC_CALCULADO AS rout_calc,
      min(eventdate) AS primera_vez,
      max(eventdate) AS ultima_vez,
      PAIS as pais_,
      SUM(CASE WHEN eventdate BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-31' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ENERO,
      SUM(CASE WHEN eventdate BETWEEN '2017-02-01' AND '2017-02-28' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FEBRERO

  FROM `Mytable`  
      WHERE  ROUTER_MAC_CALCULADO IS NOT NULL  
      GROUP BY rout_calc,pais_
```

Thanks!

Comment: what the context of this? give more details!

Comment: show the full code, show what you have done so far... 
What configurations do you have?

Comment: do you have destination table set for that query?

Comment: Since location is specified at the dataset level, I suspect the error is due to reading from `Mytable` in an EU dataset and attempting to write to a table in a US dataset.

Comment: exactly. that is my guess too :o)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43862088/bigquery-has-region-restriction-or-delay-between-other-regions