# Copy BigQuery table in other region

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

I created a process in airflow with the main goal of copying BigQuery tables between projects with different regions. But it only works if the projects are in the same region. Is there any way to solve this?

A similar question was asked 2 years ago and I would like to know if there have been any changes in this direction: [BigQuery has region restriction or delay between other regions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43862088/bigquery-has-region-restriction-or-delay-between-other-regions/43878157#43878157)

Comment: Support for [copying datasets](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets), including across regions, is now in Beta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Sharing the answer from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68531325/7883783)

Table copy only works when source and destination tables are in the same region. A workaround solution could be:

1. create a `temp_source` dataset in the same region as the source table
2. copy the source table to `temp_source` dataset
3. create `temp_destination` dataset in the same region at the wanted destination (asia-south1 in your case)
4. use the BigQuery Data Transfer service (Data transfers in BigQuery cloud console)to copy `temp_source` dataset (containing your one table) to temp_destination
5. copy `temp_destination.your_table` to your wanted destination dataset (asia-south1)

Answer (score 4):

You can copy dataset using [BigQuery Copy Dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets) (in/cross-region).  The copy dataset UI is similar to copy table. Just click "copy dataset" button from the source dataset, and specify the destination dataset in the pop-up form. See screenshot below. Check out the public documentation for more use cases.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. From helping Felipe perspective, your short comments on the question is a good enough pointer. From perspective of promoting a less known new feature (cross-region copy), an answer will be better for future user who lands on the page through search. I also agree that the answer can be better by providing more information than public documentation.

Comment: the question is about copying table between regions, you answer is about copying the datasets, what if I don't need to copy the whole dataset with all the tables?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to copy table across regions now. However this feature needs to be enabled for the projects.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#copy_tables_across_regions